# Access 2003 via Citrix: 'Error Loading DLL' with CurrentProject.Connection

Tags: ms-access, citrix

Set up an Access Project to be opened via Citrix. However, there is some VBA code that prevents it from working:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("Query")
```

The `.Connection` bit is highlighted. This works when it is not opened via Citrix though (i.e. just on users desktop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was due to the Citrix server not having the latest Jet Service Pack for Access.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of experience with ADO but I'm thinking there's a references problem of some sort.  Or that you are referencing a newer version of ADO on your system than is avaialble on the Citrix box.  Run the following code and post back the results.

```
Sub ViewReferenceDetails()

Dim ref As Reference

    For Each ref In Access.References
        Debug.Print ref.Name & " - " & ref.Major & "." & ref.Minor & " - " & ref.FullPath
    Next ref

End Sub
```

Also when you state Access project do you mean an ADP against SQL Server or an MDB/ACCDB against an Access data file?

Comment: It is an ADP (Access 2000 format) with SQL Server 2005 backend

Comment: References are fine... problem does not seem to occur now ... I think the Citrix admins may have updated MDAC 2.8 to the latest service packs.. or related to the fact Citrix pointed to the file directly, rather than as a parameter to MSACCESS.exe

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks wrong to me.  Should the rs Object not be a Recordset?

i.e.

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
'Instead of
Dim rs As ADODB.Connection
```

The code should not run at all - you should receive a Type Mismatch error.